# Does Svelte in Dev mode auto add class name?

Tags: class, dom, components, svelte

I'm currently looking for a way to capture only svelte components on the DOM tree during development mode. I can see that we I run `npm run dev` all elements and conponents have the "class='svelte-somerandomID'". Does this only happen in development mode?

Comment: What you mean by 'capture only svelte components'? You find classnames like `svelte-abc123` when you did styling inside the component, because styling is scoped https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-style - this is always, not only in dev mode

Comment: When I ```npm run dev``` and go to my localhost, then using the inspect tool on my webpage I can see the DOM through the elements tab on the dev tools. 

I want to parse out only the Svelte components out of the DOM. I noticed that every element/component made through svelte had an class attached to it so I've been using 

```const svelteComponets = document.querySelectorAll(`[class^="svelte"]`);```

to grab all svelte elements. I wasn't sure if it was only during dev mode that the class names were appended. I didn't know this was because of styling. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's only in during development that *all* elements get a scoping class -- and only with some tools. Actually it's a hack we've added in [vite-plugin-svelte](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/blob/34a49b933a25579eac948c5237b48c68e462149b/packages/vite-plugin-svelte/src/utils/preprocess.ts#L86) to enable more power CSS only HMR.

The classes you're referring to are what Svelte uses to make the CSS in a component apply only to the elements of this component. It adds a class that is unique to the component to all elements that can be affected by the component's CSS, and it also modifies your CSS rules to add the same class to them.

Normally the compiler only adds the scoping class to elements that can actually be targeted by the existing CSS rules in your component. If you really want all the elements in a component to have the scoping class, you can use the same trick that I linked to above: add the following rule to your component's CSS.

```css
* {}
```

By default the generated class names are a hash of the component's CSS content. But you can also customize them with the [`cssHash` compiler option](https://svelte.dev/docs#compile-time-svelte-compile). Note that vite-plugin-svelte also changes how the class names are generated, to be based on the file name instead of the content.

Since every element in the component would be targeted by this roule, this will cause the Svelte compiler to add the scoping class to all the elements.

If you wanted to automatically generalize this to every element of every component, you may want to do it with a preprocessor (if you need some inspiration, the code I've linked too actually implement this with a preprocessor).

I'm not sure if this is what you really want though. For one thing, only elements get a scoping class: components don't get a scoping class, because components don't have dedicated elements in the DOM (only the ones you may or may not add via the component's markup). The above trick would only give you a mean to select every element of a Svelte component. There might probably be easier or cleaner ways to achieve what you really want. For example, a simple wrapping component, or an action, that would use `wrappingElement.querySelectorAll('*')` or something...

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! This helps a lot.

The goal I'm aiming for is to parse through the DOM and filter out Svelte components and push it into an array(only during development). My naive brain thought if svelte was already adding a class name to all svelte components I could just use ```const svelteComp = document.querySelectorAll(`[class^="svelte"]`)``` to grab them all but as you explained it grabs ALL svelte elements. 

I'd love to know more about wrapping components! For school I'm currently making a google chrome dev tool to visualize svelte components in a tree!